# How to get MP3 file Bitrate ? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, mp3, bitrate

how can i get `bitrate` of a MP3 File ?

Comment: mp3 can be with dynamical bitrate...

Comment: What's your mean ? so how can you see the `bitrate` property in the properties dialog of mp3 files in the windows ?

Comment: Kermia - for VBR (variable bitrate) the best you can do is take the size of the mp3 data stream and divide it by its audio length in seconds, and multiply by 8 (to convert bytes to bits). In other words, it would be an average bitrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `TAudioFile.GetMp3Info` in [Read MP3 info](http://www.delphi-library.de/topic_MP3Informationen+auslesen_16228,0.html) (just ignore the german description)

Comment: Thank you so much , That's i wanted exactly.

Answer (score 5):

MP3 Bitrate is stored in the 3rd byte of frame header so an option would be to search for the first byte with a value 255 (in theory there's should be no other bytes with all bits set to 1 before that) and bitrate should be stored two bytes after that. Following code does this:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

const
  BIT_RATE_TABLE: array [0..15] of Integer =
    (0, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 160, 192, 224, 256, 320, 0);

var
  B: Byte;
begin
  with TFileStream.Create(ParamStr(1), fmOpenRead) do begin
    try
      Position := 0;
      repeat
        Read(B, 1);
      until B = 255;
      Position := Position + 1;
      Read(B, 1);
      Writeln(BIT_RATE_TABLE[B shr 4]);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Note that this only finds bitrate of the first frame.

You can find more detailed info from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic29420.html)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create a Delphi structure to read the MP3 file format.

That format is defined here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure

This link: http://www.3delite.hu/Object%20Pascal%20Developer%20Resources/id3v2library.html

appears to contain Delphi code for reading the format as well.

More basically, every file has a format, and generally you need to create a data structure to map that format.  You then use file reading code to map the data in the file on top of structure that defines the file format.